# Apparent Paradox between Principle of Maximum Entropy and Perplexity

Tags: machine-learning, probability

As I found the principle of maximum entropy [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy):

> the probability distribution which best represents the current state of knowledge is the one with the largest entropy

And the definition of perplexity [said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity):

> perplexity is a measurement of how well a probability distribution or probability model predicts a sample. It may be used to compare probability models. A low perplexity indicates the probability distribution is good at predicting the sample.

As perplexity is $2^{H(p)}$, the question is "does higher entropy show the better probability distribution or not?". If it is, it means high perplexity is better. how should we resolve the paradox?